# make string to quaterly divided dates per year

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

**df:**

```
      date  Revenue
0   2000Q1     1517
1   2000Q2     1248
2   2000Q3     1677
3   2000Q4     1393
4   2001Q1     1558
5   2001Q2     1368
6   2001Q3     1790
7   2001Q4     1396
8   2002Q1     1638
9   2002Q2     1507
10  2002Q3     1868
11  2002Q4     1510

df = pd.DataFrame({"date": {0: "2000Q1", 1: "2000Q2", 2: "2000Q3", 3: "2000Q4", 4: "2001Q1", 5: "2001Q2",
                             6: "2001Q3", 7: "2001Q4", 8: "2002Q1", 9: "2002Q2", 10: "2002Q3",
                             11: "2002Q4"},
                    "Revenue": {0: 1517, 1: 1248, 2: 1677, 3: 1393, 4: 1558, 5: 1368, 6: 1790, 7: 1396,
                                8: 1638, 9: 1507, 10: 1868, 11: 1510}})
```

I want to convert these dates to quaterly divided dates per year(periodic date format).

**expected output:**

```
date          Revenue     
2000-03-01     1517
2000-06-01     1248
2000-09-01     1677
2000-12-01     1393
2001-03-01     1558
2001-06-01     1368
2001-09-01     1790
2001-12-01     1396
2002-03-01     1638
2002-06-01     1507
2002-09-01     1868
2002-12-01     1510
```

Comment: Could you please post your attempt? Seems like it's some trivial string processing.

Comment: i tired some dirty logic like split by 'Q'  and all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need convert to `datetime` and add 2 Months or Quarter:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.offsets.MonthOffset(2)
#alternative
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) + pd.offsets.QuarterBegin(1)
print (df)
         date  Revenue
0  2000-03-01     1517
1  2000-06-01     1248
2  2000-09-01     1677
3  2000-12-01     1393
4  2001-03-01     1558
5  2001-06-01     1368
6  2001-09-01     1790
7  2001-12-01     1396
8  2002-03-01     1638
9  2002-06-01     1507
10 2002-09-01     1868
11 2002-12-01     1510
```

Comment: in pandas document i couldn't find that we can directly convert `2000Q1` to a date format. many thanks